# Remotely controlled alarm

Tags: smart-home, wifi, hardware, google-home, remote-access

I would like to find, or if necessary, create a device that can be set to go off with a chime or alarm of some sort at certain times throughout the day. If that was all that was required, then no problem I could just get an alarm clock, however I would like for this chime to function when I am not in my home, and I would also like for it to shut off after a short amount of time automatically.

The goal is to train my pet to hear the chime and expect food, and use the chime to signal to them that there is food waiting at their automatic feeder (along with their seizure medication, that must be administered during the work day) without me or my partner needing to be present. We thought of a simple alarm clock, but were unsure if it would shut itself off after going off the first time. This could probably be remedied easily enough with an arduino and a small speaker (or something similar) but I wanted to look for a prebuilt solution first, and was unsure on how to search for a device like this.

Thinking of it a little more, we would also like to be able to trigger this alarm manually, remotely, in case the first chime does not alert our sleeping pet. This new scope is what brought me to this stack, as I am very unfamiliar with wifi communication and smart home type devices.

Ideally, I would like to be able to control the alarm from my iPhone, or through some sort of remote, while many miles away at work or on a day trip. ***Is there any pre-built or out-of-the-box-ready solution for something like this?***

We already have Amazon's Blink security cameras, and would plan to use those to monitor whether the chime worked to notify our pet to the presence of food and medicine. The cameras have a live talk feature, which might work as a manual trigger, but we would need to talk into the phone or play some sound wherever we are remotely. This is fine if necessary, but in an office at work, it would be inconvenient to have to step out to "trigger" the camera's sound (aka, essentially call my pet to their food manually with my own voice) Additionally, this feature must be activated manually, and I was looking more for something that was *autonomous*, at least until I could check and see that the chime did not wake my pet, and then *if needed* activate additional alarms until they come and get it.

Any advice here? If this is the wrong forum for such a question, please let me know!

---

*EDIT: In response to some comments, the pet is a cat, I would still like the chime as a safeguard, seeing as the medication makes her extra drowsy, even more than a normal cat, and sometimes disorganized (it is a neurologic medicine after all, lol) The chime is to help out in the case that she is extra zonked out in another room.*

*I am hoping that I have been specific enough in my requirements that this remains open and on topic, if need though, I suppose I could just remove the bit asking for a prebuilt solution, and only request DIY solutions, but why re-invent the wheel? :)*

*I also wanted to bring up that I do actually have a Google Home Mini that I could set up. My first thought when I found it were that there are alarms I could set, but seeing as I would not be home to shut it off, it would continue to chime for [10 minutes](https://support.google.com/googlenest/answer/7071598?hl=en&ref_topic=7028797) which is undesirable, but not the end of the world. Any new suggestions with the addition of an available Home Mini?*

Comment: `Is there any pre-built or out-of-the-box-ready solution for something like this?` ... shopping questions are off topic here

Comment: is this for a dog or a cat? ... you may not need a chime ...  dogs and cats have a very good internal clock ... they will most likely be waiting at the food dispenser shortly before it dispenses dinner ... the sound of the dispenser should also alert them

Comment: Welcome to Internet of Things! As [stated on meta](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/176/49) shopping questions ***are on topic*** if they are clear and specific about the exact requirements.

Comment: @jsotola I've updated the question with relevant information